# Parse a session data with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a data that came from a session and I want to parse base on regex. Below are the 3 data that I want to get login, firstName and lastName.

```
login = James 
firstName = James.S 
lastName = Steal


Array (
[user] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object (
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => DEX_User
    [permissionID:DE_User:private] => 9
    [login:DE_User:private] => James.S
    [email:DE_User:private] => james.s@domain.com
    [firstName:DE_User:private] => James
    [lastName:DE_User:private] => Steal
    [title:DE_User:private] => Warehouse Man
    [manager:DE_User:private] => Manager's Name
    [workPhone:DE_User:private] => +1 (111) 111-1111
    [mobilePhone:DE_User:private] => +1 (222) 222-2222
    [homePhone:DE_User:private] => +1 (333) 333-3333
    [im:DE_User:private] =>
    [timeDelta:DE_User:private] => Asia/Hongkong
    [lastLogin:DE_User:private] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object ( 
        [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => GB_Date
        [valueStored:protected] => 13545544126666309821
        [mode:protected] => BASE
        [master:protected] =>
    )
    [description:DE_User:private] => Warehouse Engineer
    [isActive:DE_User:private] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object (
        [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => GB_Boolean
        [valueStored:protected] => 1
        [mode:protected] => BASE
        [master:protected] =>
    )
    [isTerminate:DE_User:private] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object (
        [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => GB_Boolean
        [valueStored:protected] =>
        [mode:protected] => BASE
        [master:protected] =>
    )
    [id:protected] => 231968
    [isModifyed:protected] => 
    [needInsert:protected] => 
    [isDeleted] => 
    [isRemoved] => 
)
[enter_password] => 2asas(qwqw)
```

I tried to perform regexp `'/\[[\/]?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]/';` but i can only get that inside the bracket.

Thank you.

Comment: Wait, where did this info come from? It is `var_dump()/print_r()` output.  You should _not_ be storing this in `$_SESSION`. Instead the object itself can be stored in `$_SESSION` which will correctly handle the serialization/unserialization on its own.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski, yes it is came from print_r(). This data is system generated from an application which I don't have control with the source, so I only have the option to use session_start() then parse that data so I could get what I need. as you can see the object is private and I couldn't access it data outside the object. am right?

Comment: Have you tried `serializing`/`deserializing` the object and then trying to access the properties? Also, there should be a method on `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` to access these protected properties. Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead  of parsing it using RegExp you may evaluate it.

Take a look at `var_export($_SESSION['user']);` . This returns a parseable string, the only problem you will see there is :

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class::__set_state
```

"__PHP_Incomplete_Class" means, the class was unknown when the Session was started, the string still can't be parsed.

But you can take the string returned by `var_export($_SESSION['user'],true)` , replace the occurences of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class::__set_state` with `array` and the string can be evaluated:

```
eval('$user='.str_replace('__PHP_Incomplete_Class::__set_state',
                          'array',
                          var_export($_SESSION['user'],true)).';');

echo $user[0]['login'].',<br/>'.
     $user[0]['firstName'].',<br/>'.
     $user[0]['lastName'];
```

Comment: hi @Dr.Molle, idea is great and it works perfectly. thanks a million.